# change port no on which tomcat is installed in ubuntu using SSH

Tags: ubuntu, port, tomcat

I am accessing an Ubuntu instance through SSH, I installed tomcat7 on it. By default installed on port 8080.
I need to install on port 9090, is there a way to change the port? Or how to install tomcat on a specific port?

Searched internet but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config subdirectory you will find a configuration file containing ports to be used.  Change 8080 to 9090 in this file and restart tomcat.

You can use the can use the command `netstat -ant | grep LISTEN` to verify you have a listener on port 9090.  You could also browse locally to the server, using `get`, `w3m`, `curl`, or whichever tool is installed.

The command `iptables -L -n can be used to see if you have a local firewall blocking the port.  If the system is tightly secured, you will need to add a rule to allow access on port 9090.

Comment: Thanks for answering, tried editing the file. Giving me access denied error. It is an ubuntu machine on AWS.

Comment: @AnilBhaskar Added some testing hints.